# Add csv and excel export button in dataTables Laravel

Tags: laravel

I want to add csv and excel export button to one dataTable only.
MyController file:

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $Databaseurl = Route('orders.index');
    if ($request->ajax()) {
        $orders = Order::all();
        return datatables()->of($orders)
            ->editColumn('price', function ($order) {
                return '<div class="text-nowrap text-center">'.number_format($order->price, 0, '.', ',').'</div>';
            })
            ->editColumn('address', function ($order) {
                return \Illuminate\Support\Str::limit($order->address,25);
            })
            ->editColumn('city', function ($order) {
                return '<div class="text-center">'.\Illuminate\Support\Str::limit($order->city,25).'</div>';
            })
            ->addIndexColumn()
            ->addColumn('action', function($order){
                return '<a href="'.route('order.edit',['id' => $order->id]).'" class="text-nowrap btn-sm btn-primary text-center"><i class="far fa-eye"></i> view</a>';
            })
            ->rawColumns(['action','city','price'])
            ->toJson();
    }
    return view('order.index',compact('Databaseurl'));
}
```

and the data table jquery codes:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        var table = $('.mydatatable').DataTable({
            "oLanguage": {
                "sUrl": "https://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.19/i18n/Persian.json",
            },
            "pageLength": 25,
            processing: true,
            serverSide: true,
            ajax: "{{ $Databaseurl }}",
            columns: [
                {data: 'id', name: 'id'},
                {data: 'customer_name', name: 'customer_name'},
                {data: 'address', name: 'address', searchable: false},
                {data: 'city', name: 'city'},
                {data: 'price', name: 'price', searchable: false},
                {data: 'created_at', name: 'created_at', searchable: false},
                {data: 'action', name: 'action', orderable:false,searchable: false},
            ],
        });
    });
</script>
```

Also I watched [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SknUDJQvbh0), but I prefer not to go through more difficult steps and solve this problem in the same controller and blade file.
Because I only want this for one view table
Is there a solution?

Answer (score 2):

After some days, I found this way:
first add this links to your blode file:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.0.3/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css">

<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.6.4/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
```

Then add this following codes to the js datatable codes:

```
 dom: 'Bfrtip',
 buttons: [
      'copy', 'excel',
 ],
```